# Knowing which docker vxlan network uses a specific gateway

Tags: docker, networking, gateway

Is there a way to know which one of the networks using the vxlan driver is configured to use a specific gateway without inspecting all the networks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker network ls` currently supports following filters:

- driver
- id (network’s id)
- label (label= or label==)
- name (network’s name)
- scope (swarm|global|local)
- type (custom|builtin)

Unless you label your networks with gateway used by it, you need to list all networks and inspect each of them.